# Is it possible to locate a Google map address on the basis of MAC Address in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm working on a wifi map locator. Is it possible to locate all available wifi networks on the Google map on the basis of a MAC address? Or is there any way to do that? Thanks

Comment: Are you aware that a device (ie. a MAC address) can move, I mean I can go anywhere I want with my smartphone..

Comment: From how I understand the question this is exactly what Android does when determining location based on WiFi? MAC and Signal strengths of near Access Points.

Comment: Still not clear to me what you are asking

Comment: You can use [this](http://samy.pl/androidmap/) website to map by using `MAC Address`. Also, there is `WiFi access point objects` in `Google Maps Geolocation API`, which you can check [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/geolocation/#wifi_access_point_object).

Comment: @cYrixmorten: I want to display All open available wifi hotspots on google maps using android code .